# Firebase hosting: www.example.com redirect to example.com says "domain not verified"

Tags: godaddy, domain-registrar, firebase

I have bought a domain from GoDaddy, and I want to host a static website using firebase hosting. When connected to firebase, `example.com` works. But when I want to redirect `www.example.com` to `example.com`, it doesn't work. I already put token generated from Firebase into GoDaddy registrar.

It says 'Domain not verified'.
[image]

This is my records in godaddy.

[image]

I have waited for a day, still it doesn't work.

---

What could have gone wrong in my setting up the redirection? This is my first time setting up hosting, sorry if I'm making silly mistakes.

Comment: In order to redirect from `www` to `non-www`, you first need to add a DNS record for the `www` subdomain in GoDaddy. You can do that using an [A](https://www.godaddy.com/help/add-an-a-record-19238) record, or [CNAME](https://www.godaddy.com/help/add-a-cname-record-19236). Then you'll need to add a `TXT` record for the Firebase verification. [This](https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-firebase-hosting-custom-domain-the-missing-manual-7f971c3c2d1e) guide should help with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was frustrating to get stuck in that, but after a while, I figure out Godaddy has a built in subdomain registration. To solve this problem, simply got `GoDaddy`->`Select your domain`->`DNS Management`->Scroll down to `Forwarding` and add subdomain `www`.

**Example:**

[image: Example]

Answer (score 9):

I have had the same issue, `example.com` worked just fine but `www.example.com` didn't. Turned out that `www.example.com` needs `www` in the `name` value instead of `@` for reason unknown, But `@` worked for `example.com`.

And I didn't redirect `www.example.com` to `example.com`.

So currently I have four entries in my godaddy console for my domain, two with `@` and two with `www`. See below. Hope that helps.

[image: GoDaddy DNS Console Settings For Firebase Hosting]

Comment: The "Name" field is for the name of the subdomain.  "www" is a subdomain.   The "@" means the domain apex or "no subdomain".     That should make your "unknown reason" clearer I hope.   Otherwise this is a good answer.   It is basically fully explaining how to create the DNS records for "www" as suggested by Dan in a comment.

Comment: I'm using Google Domains but had the same problem, and the solution is the same.  I needed to remove an existing row for name "www" and type "CNAME", and then add a new line for name "www" and type "A" with the values given by firebase for the values.  Google Domains doesn't use multiple rows for multiple values.  You can add multiple values to the same row.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with whogohost by adding

[image]

And also adding the this
[image]