# redirecting from www url to non-www url in Google Firebase static hosting

Tags: redirects, 302-redirect, firebase, 303-redirect

I am using Google Firebase static hosting.

When a user types and enters `www.example.com`, I want the address to change to `example.com` and show the user content of example.com.

How can this be achieved? E.g. In Firebase, can I say that I want that subdomain to be redirected there? I don't think there is a .htaccess file.

Note:

Answers to this [question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/116852/firebase-hosting-www-example-com-redirect-to-example-com-not-working) that advise on dns seems to be only one part of the solution. I talked with my domain name and dns manager (Hostinger) tech support, and they insist that there are things to be done on Firebase.

Answer (score 2):

In Firebase click the button to add a custom domain to your site. In the opened window, there is a checkbox that if checked will make that custom domain a redirect for another address. I used that and works.